# jQuery filter with drop down box using data-type

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to filter through rows of a table using a drop-down box with jQuery. What I can't figure out how to do is how to relate the value of the options to the data-type of the table rows.

HTML:

```
<label for="filter">Type:</label>
<select id="filter>
    <option value="all">All Steps</option>
    <option value="standard">Standards</option>
    <option value="review">Reviews</option>
</select>

<table id="table>
    <tr id="one" class="row" data-type="standard">
        <td>Standard</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="one" class="row" data-type="review">
        <td>Reviews</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$("#filter").change(function () {
$("#table").find(data-type).each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() != $("#filter").val()) 
        $(this).hide();
    else 
        $(this).parent().show();
    if ($("#filter").val() == "all") 
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```

The jQuery here is just pieced together based off of what I've found so far by researching around. It's important that I leave the data-type attribute in the table rows.

I'm pretty new to jQuery, so anything helps!

Here's the Code Pen: http://codepen.io/aburnsworth/pen/XKzgqa?editors=1111

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You find you what value is selected by using `.val();`

You get all the rows you need that `.val()` to match against `$('.row');`

Loop all the rows when you find a match hide all, only then show what you want, b/c computer do this so fast seems instant

```
.each(function(index, element) {});
```

Now you have a filter

EDIT: just move the hide all outside of the loop should do it.

```js
$(".filter").change(function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).val();
    var row = $('.row'); 
      
    row.hide()
    row.each(function(i, el) {
         if($(el).attr('data-type') == filterValue) {
             $(el).show();
         }
    })
     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="filter">Type:</label>
<select class="filter" data-tableId="table1">
  <option value="all">All Steps</option>
  <option value="standard">Standards</option>
  <option value="review">Reviews</option>
  <option value="inspection">Inspections</option>    <option value="payment">Payments</option>
  <option value="document">Documents</option>
</select>

<table id="table1">
  <tr id="one" class="row" data-type="standard">
    <td>Standard</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="two"  class="row" data-type="review">
    <td>Review</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="three" class="row" data-type="inspection">
    <td>Inspections</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="four" class="row" data-type="payment">
    <td>Payments</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="five" class="row" data-type="document">
    <td>Documents</td>
  </tr>
   <tr id="one" class="row" data-type="standard">
    <td>Standard</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="two"  class="row" data-type="review">
    <td>Review</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="three" class="row" data-type="inspection">
    <td>Inspections</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="four" class="row" data-type="payment">
    <td>Payments</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="five" class="row" data-type="document">
    <td>Documents</td>
</table>
```

Comment: This works except for one thing. If I had another row with the same data-type it only displays the last one of that type. What I'm applying this for will have multiple of the same data-types all throughout the table.

Comment: What is the way to do it without changing the HTML? I couldn't get your last edit to work.

Comment: I forgot to mention you need to change all your id to class since id can not be duplicated.

Comment: see how I have to change id="filter" to class="filter", and id="table" to id="table1", id="table2"

Comment: Why did you add another table?

Comment: The original code you had works if you move the hide outside of the loop as you suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your js function to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       var $rows = $('table tr');
       $("#filter").change(function() {

           var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
               reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
               text;
           if ($(this).val() !== 'all') {

               $rows.show().filter(function() {
                   text = $(this).data('type').replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
                   return !reg.test(text);
               }).hide();

           } else {
               $rows.show();
           }
       });
   });
```

Please see this working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HectorBarbossa/56xjmc18/).

Answer (score 2):

In Addition to @wlin's Answer 
For "All" value in dropdown.

```js
$("#filter").change(function() {
  console.clear();
  var filterValue = $(this).val();
  var row = $('.row');

  row.each(function(i, el) {
    if ($(el).attr('data-type') == filterValue) {
      row.hide()
      $(el).show();
    }
  });
// In Addition to Wlin's Answer (For "All" value)
  if ("all" == filterValue) {
    row.show();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="filter">Type:</label>
<select id="filter">
  <option value="all">All Steps</option>
  <option value="standard">Standards</option>
  <option value="review">Reviews</option>
  <option value="inspection">Inspections</option>
  <option value="payment">Payments</option>
  <option value="document">Documents</option>
</select>

<table id="table">
  <tr id="one" class="row" data-type="standard">
    <td>Standard</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="two" class="row" data-type="review">
    <td>Review</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="three" class="row" data-type="inspection">
    <td>Inspections</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="four" class="row" data-type="payment">
    <td>Payments</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="five" class="row" data-type="document">
    <td>Documents</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please update the code so its able to show multiple items that have the same type value, currently this only shows one.