# How to add a jQuery filter to a html table

Tags: php, jquery, filter

I'm trying to add a jquery drop down filter to a table being pulled from the database

I referred to a few similar questions and got the code from one of them. I could make the drop down front end working but got stuck with the back end.

report.php

```
<div id="container">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<label for="filter">Gender:</label>
<select class="filter" data-tableId="myTable">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
  <body>
  <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf019;</i>
  </body>
   </html>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id ="myTable" class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th> First Name </th>
          <th> Last Name </th>                  
          <th> Phone </th>
          <th> Email </th>              
          <th> Gender </th>
          <th> Action </th>  
        </tr>
      </thead> 
      <?php
        if (count($report) === 0) {
            echo "<tr>No Reports</tr>";
        } else {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($report); $i++) {
                echo
                "<tr>
                    <td>{$report[$i]['FName']}</td>
                    <td>{$report[$i]['LName']}</td>
                    <td>{$report[$i]['HPhone']}</td>
                    <td>{$report[$i]['PEmail']}</td>
                    <td>{$report[$i]['Gender']}</td>

                    <td><a class=btn href='read.php?id=".$report[$i]['RegId']."'>Read</a></td>    
                </tr>"; 
            }
        }
      ?>
    </table> 
</div>
```

main.js

```
$(".filter").change(function() {
  var filterValue = $(this).val();
  var row = $('.row'); 

  row.hide();
  row.each(function(i, el) {
    if($(el).attr('data-type') === filterValue) {
      $(el).show();
    }
  }); 
});
```

I want to put the filter on the gender column of the table.

I'm sure there's some mistake in main.js and have been trying to figure it out for a while now but couldn't find it.  I'm new to jquery, any help would be appreciated. TIA

Comment: First of where do you add the class `.row`, cant seem to locate it in your html?  also i can't see where you add `data-type` to an element

Comment: That's supposed to be the id and class of the tr, not sure how and where to put it in there

Comment: I'm sure the problem is not within you jquery but with your `php` each loop, you dont seem to add the `row` class or the `data-type` anywhere there

Comment: yeah maybe. Any idea on how it should be done?

Comment: I referred to the following question and got the jquery from there
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334897/jquery-filter-with-drop-down-box-using-data-type

Comment: I guess it would be `<tr class="row" data-type="{$report[$i]['WHATEVERTHEVALUENAMEIS']}">`

Comment: Wouldn't it come under the td class?

Comment: Not if you at the post you just linked, Look at how they do it and it should be simple.

Comment: Yeah I've been doing that, I can't put class and data-type in a loop. The editor isn't letting me do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to handle this task.

HTML code:

```
<form name="formobject" method="POST" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="formrstatus" value="">
<select class="filter" data-tableId="myTable" onchange="checkValue(this.value)">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
</form>

<script>
</script>
function checkValue(id){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url:"/someurl",
dataType: 'JSON',
data: {id},
success: function(response) {
                //use this response to fetch table data
},
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

   }
});
}

/*Use api to fetch the values according to the posted value and return the json encoded value, something like this*/

<?php
$id=encodestring($_POST["id"]);

$sql="select * from sometable where gender='".$id."'";
$result= $mysqli->query($sql);

$vars[] = array($res);

echo json_encode($vars);
?>
```